# Can [[UILocalNotification alloc] init] be nil?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

The [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) uses this code:

```
//...etc..
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
//...etc..
```

I am wondering what could be the scenarios in which localNotif is nil?

Otherwise, I don't see the point of having that if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a generic protection against a failed alloc/init, just like standard -init code includes the nil check (`if (self == nil) { ... }`), even though on modern systems it's extremely unlikely that the alloc fails.

Answer (score -3):

Try disabling *all* notifications for your app (including sound/badge).

Comment: I did, the localNotif is not nil in that case either!